# Include argument in NAnt executable call if property is not null or empty

Tags: conditional-statements, nant, isnullorempty

For a build script, part of my process is to deploy files using an in-house executable.  We call this with a number of parameters.

On an application I'm working on, it turns out we need to add a parameter.  This isn't something that retroactively applies to anything else I've previously worked on, so the idea is that I would only include the new argument if the corresponding property is not null or empty.

**Relevant NAnt Call:**

```
<property name="deploy.NewArg" value="" />
<echo message="deploy.NewArg = ${deploy.NewArg}" />

<exec program="C:\Deploy\MyAwesomeDeployProgram.exe">
    <arg value="AppTitle=${deploy.AppTitle}" />
    <arg value="Environment=${deploy.Environment}" />
    <!-- Here's the problem argument... -->
    <arg value="MyNewProperty=${deploy.NewArg}" if="${deploy.NewArg}" />
</exec>
```

The reason what I have is not working, is because of the `if` clause on the new `<arg>` tag - the `deploy.NewArg` string doesn't convert to a boolean statement.

**Question:** In what way can I perform an "Is Null or Empty" check on an `<arg if>` parameter?  As noted above, I want the `MyNewProperty=...` argument added if `deploy.NewArg` is anything but nothing or an empty string.

I checked a number of other StackOverflow questions, as well as the [official NAnt arg tag documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/elements/NAnt.Core.Types.Argument.html), but could not find how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, I needed to get back to the basics, and check out some of my fundamentals and functions.  The way to do an 'is empty' check on a property is as below:

```
<exec program="C:\Deploy\MyAwesomeDeployProgram.exe">
    <!-- Other args... -->
    <arg value="MyNewProperty=${deploy.NewArg}" if=${string::get-length(deploy.NewArg) > 0}" />
</exec>
```

For someone who hasn't yet done the research, `if` only works with a boolean.  That being said, booleans can be generated in one of two ways: either an explicit `true` or `false`, or by using an expression.  Expressions are always contained in `${}` brackets.  The use of `string::get-length()` should be obvious.

Bring it all together, and you only include an argument if it's specified.